# Segmentation fault thrown when trying to set pixels values of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

My code :

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat origin = cv::imread("../resources/Slide2.JPG");

    for(int c = 0; c != origin.cols; ++c)
        for(int r = 0; r != origin.rows; ++r)
            origin.at<cv::Vec3b>(c,r) = {3,3,3};

    cv::imshow("test",origin);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

[The image file](https://github.com/Mooophy/vision-and-homogeneous-transform/blob/master/resources/Slide2.JPG)

When debugging, it was stuck at `Mat::release()` in `mat.hpp`:

```
inline void Mat::release()
{
    if( refcount && CV_XADD(refcount, -1) == 1 )
        deallocate();
    data = datastart = dataend = datalimit = 0;
    size.p[0] = 0;
    refcount = 0;
}
```

What's going on here?How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch `r` and `c` in `.at()` call:

```
origin.at<cv::Vec3b>(r, c) = {3,3,3};
```

Comment: in addition you should flip the loop order, rows in outer loop, cols in inner loop, to get a more efficient access pattern!